# How To Create Action Items For Specific Customer In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

New to Rails. New to OOP. I have a client and action_item model. An action item (a todo) has many and belongs to many clients. A client, has many action items. Essentially: A user, creates TODO's, from client pages.

User: creates a client (Crayola LLC, for ex) with crud. 
User is then on the Client's show page (Crayola LLC's show page). 
**My question is, HOW TO have:** User to be able to create an action item, for that client. Example: Call Crayola, to sell them an upgrade).

Created join table called action_items_clients, with foreign keys client_id, and action_item_id. Ran migration. Just have no idea how to facilitate creation of action items FOR clients. As it stands, action items can be created without clients. That's simple crud. This is where my novice understanding of rails hits roadblocks.

Action Items Controller:

class ActionItemsController < ApplicationController

```
def index
    @action_items = ActionItem.all


end 

def new
    @action_items = ActionItem.new
end

def create
        @action_item = ActionItem.new(action_items_params)
        if @action_item.save
            redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @action_item.id)
            #renders client individual page
        else 
            redirect_to(:action => 'new')
        end
end

def edit
    @action_item = ActionItem.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @action_item = ActionItem.find(params[:id])
    if @action_item.update_attributes(action_items_params)
        redirect_to(:controller => 'action_items', :action => 'show', :id => @action_item.id)
        flash[:notice] = "Updated"
        else 
            render 'new'

    end 
end


def show
    @action_item = ActionItem.find(params[:id])


end

def action_clients
    @action_clients = ActionItem.Client.new 
end



def delete
    @action_items = ActionItem.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @action_items = ActionItem.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to(:controller => 'action_items', :action => 'index')
end

private 
def action_items_params
    params.require(:action_item).permit(:purpose, :correspondence_method, :know_person, :contact_name_answer, :additional_notes)
end
```

end

Clients controller

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

def index
@clients = Client.all
end

def new 
@client = Client.new
end

def create
@client = Client.new(clients_params)
    if @client.save
        redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @client.id)
        #renders client individual page
    else 
        redirect_to(:action => 'new')
    end

end 

def edit
@client = Client.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@client = Client.find(params[:id])
  if @client.update_attributes(clients_params)
  redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @client.id)
else 
  render 'edit'
 end
end

def show
@client = Client.find(params[:id])

end

def delete
@client = Client.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
@client = Client.find(params[:id]).destroy
redirect_to(:controller => 'clients', :action => 'index')
end

private
def clients_params
params.require(:client).permit(:name)
end


end
```

Show page for each client:

```
<div align="center"><h1> <%= @client.name %> </h1></div>

<ol><li><%= link_to('Enter Definition Mode', :controller => 'action_items', :action  => 'new', :id => @client.id) %></br></br></li> 

<li><%= link_to('Back to client List', :controller => 'clients', :action => 'index')  %> </li></br>

</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is setup your routes so that action_items are nested under the client, something like so:

```
# /clients/13/action_items
resources :clients do
  resources :action_items
end
```

Or if the user logging in *is* a client or only has one client, then you could skip that, and just have `resources :action_items`.

Then if you direct a user to `/clients/13/action_items`, then they will hit `action_items#index`, and `params[:client_id]` will be set to `13`. You can use this to scope the action_items throughout that controller.

As long as you have the relationships setup between `Client` and `ActionItem` setup:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :action_items
end
class ActionItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

It is probably also good to scope that to the currently logged in user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
end
```

but it depends on how you want things to work. This is probably how I'd structure things:

```
class ActionItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_client

  def index
    @action_items = @client.action_items.all
  end

  def new
    @action_items = @client.action_items.new
  end

  def create
    @action_item = @client.action_items.new(action_items_params)
    if @action_item.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @action_item.id, :client_id => @client.id)
    else 
      redirect_to(:action => 'new')
    end
  end

  # and other actions....

  private

  def get_client
    @client = current_user.clients.find(params[:client_id])
  end
end
```

**EDIT (to address some commented questions):**

If the action_items aren't always scoped to a client, they can live under both a nested and an un-nested route at the same time:

```
# /action_items
resources :action_items

resources :clients do
  # /clients/13/action_items
  resources :action_items
end
```

Then the `before_action` can be a bit more generic to set the `owner` to either the client, or the user itself (as long as `User` also `has_and_belongs_to_many :action_items`):

```
class ActionItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_owner

  def index
    @action_items = @owner.action_items.all
  end

  # ... other stuff

  private

  def get_owner
    if params[:client_id].present?
      @owner = current_user.clients.find(params[:client_id])
    else
      @owner = current_user
    end
  end
end
```

Your redirects will probably need to take into account whether they came from a nested page or not, so you might have some logic like this around them:

```
def destroy
  item = @owner.action_items.find(params[:id])
  item.destroy
  if params[:client_id]
    redirect_to client_action_items_path(params[:client_id])
  else
    redirect_to action_items_path
  end
end
```

Your `link_to`s will also have to change similarly, here's a link to the above destroy action:

```
<% if params[:client_id].present? %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete action item', client_action_item_path(params[:client_id], @action_item), :method => 'delete' %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete action item', @action_item, :method => 'delete' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Killer - I will implement this later on tonight, and mark this answered. Thanks for your help. And thanks for your support on answering questions. Super helpful in learning process. -- The relationships are in fact set up. The concern I see right away, is what if a user, needs to create an action item that is not tied directly to clients. The application (to explain) is an action item creation program for small/medium businesses. A user might create an action item for: operations (company operations) as well, in which case it would need to not be tied to clients. Make sense? And suggestions?

Comment: "You can use this to scope the action_items throughout that controller." - what exactly to you mean? -- Now, I have clients/42/action_items sending user to action_items#index - that works.

Comment: Also - the delete link on that action items index page, now leads to the action items show page somehow. This has to be a routing issue. I changed nothing else.

Comment: Got it - Looking through this now. Will be fussing with it all for a while !